# How to add the first values in cascading columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Can anyone help me with a better solution than looping? Let's say that we have the following pandas data-frame made out of 4 columns. I am looking for a way to get the same values as in "Result" column through other methods than looping.

Here is the logic:

- If priority1=1 then result=1
- If priority1=1 and priority2=1 then result=2 (ignore all other if priority1 !=1)
- If priority1=1 and priority2=1 and priority3=1 then result=3 (ignore all other if priority1 and priority2 != 1)
- If priority1=1 and priority2=1 and priority3=1 and priority4=1 then result=4 (ignore all other if priority1 and priority2 and priority3 != 1)

The opposite is happening if priority1 is negative.

Here is my final result after a very ugly and inefficient looping:

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|     | priority1 | priority2 | priority3 | priority4 | Result |
+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|   0 |           |           |           |           |        |
|   1 |           |         1 |        -1 |        -1 |        |
|   2 |           |           |           |           |        |
|   3 |           |           |           |         1 |        |
|   4 |           |           |           |         1 |        |
|   5 |           |           |           |           |        |
|   6 |           |           |           |        -1 |        |
|   7 |           |           |           |           |        |
|   8 |           |           |           |           |        |
|   9 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |      1 |
|  10 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  11 |           |           |           |         1 |        |
|  12 |           |           |         1 |           |        |
|  13 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  14 |           |           |        -1 |        -1 |        |
|  15 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  16 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  17 |           |           |           |        -1 |        |
|  18 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  19 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  20 |           |         1 |         1 |         1 |      2 |
|  21 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  22 |           |           |        -1 |        -1 |        |
|  23 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  24 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  25 |           |           |           |        -1 |        |
|  26 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  27 |           |           |         1 |         1 |      3 |
|  28 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  29 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  30 |           |           |           |        -1 |        |
|  31 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  32 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  33 |           |           |        -1 |        -1 |        |
|  34 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  35 |           |           |         1 |         1 |      4 |
|  36 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  37 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  38 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  39 |           |           |        -1 |        -1 |        |
|  40 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  41 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  42 |           |         1 |         1 |         1 |      2 |
|  43 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  44 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  45 |           |           |           |        -1 |        |
|  46 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  47 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  48 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  49 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  50 |           |        -1 |        -1 |        -1 |        |
|  51 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  52 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  53 |           |         1 |         1 |         1 |      2 |
|  54 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  55 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  56 |           |           |           |        -1 |        |
|  57 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  58 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  59 |           |           |        -1 |        -1 |        |
|  60 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  61 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  62 |           |           |         1 |         1 |      3 |
|  63 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  64 |        -1 |        -1 |        -1 |        -1 |     -1 |
|  65 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  66 |           |           |         1 |         1 |        |
|  67 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  68 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  69 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  70 |           |           |           |        -1 |        |
|  71 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  72 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  73 |           |           |         1 |         1 |        |
|  74 |           |           |           |        -1 |        |
|  75 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  76 |           |           |         1 |         1 |        |
|  77 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  78 |           |        -1 |        -1 |        -1 |     -2 |
|  79 |           |           |         1 |           |        |
|  80 |           |           |         1 |         1 |        |
|  81 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  82 |           |           |        -1 |        -1 |     -3 |
|  83 |           |           |         1 |         1 |        |
|  84 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  85 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  86 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  87 |           |           |        -1 |        -1 |     -4 |
|  88 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  89 |           |        -1 |        -1 |        -1 |     -2 |
|  90 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  91 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  92 |           |           |           |        -1 |        |
|  93 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  94 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  95 |           |           |         1 |         1 |        |
|  96 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  97 |           |           |           |           |        |
|  98 |           |           |           |        -1 |        |
|  99 |           |           |           |         1 |        |
| 100 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 101 |           |           |        -1 |        -1 |     -3 |
| 102 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 103 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 104 |           |         1 |         1 |         1 |        |
| 105 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 106 |           |           |           |         1 |        |
| 107 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 108 |           |           |        -1 |        -1 |        |
| 109 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 110 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 111 |           |           |         1 |         1 |        |
| 112 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 113 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 114 |           |           |        -1 |        -1 |        |
| 115 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 116 |           |           |         1 |         1 |        |
| 117 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 118 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 119 |           |        -1 |        -1 |        -1 |     -2 |
| 120 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 121 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 122 |           |           |           |         1 |        |
| 123 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 124 |           |           |           |         1 |        |
| 125 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 126 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 127 |           |           |         1 |         1 |        |
| 128 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 129 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 130 |           |           |        -1 |        -1 |     -3 |
| 131 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 132 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 133 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 134 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |      1 |
| 135 |           |           |           |        -1 |        |
| 136 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 137 |           |        -1 |        -1 |        -1 |        |
| 138 |           |           |         1 |           |        |
| 139 |           |           |           |         1 |        |
| 140 |           |         1 |         1 |         1 |      2 |
| 141 |           |           |         1 |         1 |      3 |
| 142 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 143 |           |           |           |        -1 |        |
| 144 |           |           |           |           |        |
| 145 |           |           |           |         1 |      4 |
+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic again? Would the result be 4 if all priorities are equal to 1? If I see your last column, result is 4 when only priority 4 ==1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [ 1,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 1,  1,  0,  0],
        [ 1,  1,  1,  0],
        [ 1,  1,  1,  1],
        [ 0,  1,  1,  1],
        [ 0,  0,  1,  1],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  1],
        [ 1,  0,  1,  1],  # this should end up 1
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [-1,  0,  0,  0],
        [-1, -1,  0,  0],
        [-1, -1, -1,  0],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [ 0, -1, -1, -1],
        [ 0,  0, -1, -1],
        [ 0,  0,  0, -1],
    ], columns=['priority{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 5)])
```

***solution***

```
v = df.values
df.assign(Results=(v * v.cumprod(1).astype(np.bool8)).sum(1))

    priority1  priority2  priority3  priority4  Results
0           1          0          0          0        1
1           1          1          0          0        2
2           1          1          1          0        3
3           1          1          1          1        4
4           0          1          1          1        0
5           0          0          1          1        0
6           0          0          0          1        0
7           1          0          1          1        1
8           0          0          0          0        0
9          -1          0          0          0       -1
10         -1         -1          0          0       -2
11         -1         -1         -1          0       -3
12         -1         -1         -1         -1       -4
13          0         -1         -1         -1        0
14          0          0         -1         -1        0
15          0          0          0         -1        0
```

***how it works***

Grab the `numpy` array with

```
v = df.values
```

non-zeros as `True` with

```
v.astype(np.bool8)
```

each successive column continuing to be non-zero with

```
v.astype(np.bool8).cumprod(1)
```

multiply by `v` to filter out which ones to add then sum

```
(v * v.astype(np.bool8).cumprod(1)).sum()
```

***naive time test***
*small data*

[image]

*big data*

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer and for the guidance of how it works :)

Answer (score 3):

Using piRSquared's example frame (hat tip!), I might do something like

```
match = (df.abs() == 1) & (df.eq(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0))
out = match.cumprod(axis=1).sum(axis=1) * df.iloc[:, 0]
```

which gives me

```
In [107]: df["Result"] = out

In [108]: df
Out[108]: 
    priority1  priority2  priority3  priority4  Result
0           1          0          0          0       1
1           1          1          0          0       2
2           1          1          1          0       3
3           1          1          1          1       4
4           0          1          1          1       0
5           0          0          1          1       0
6           0          0          0          1       0
7           0          0          0          0       0
8          -1          0          0          0      -1
9          -1         -1          0          0      -2
10         -1         -1         -1          0      -3
11         -1         -1         -1         -1      -4
12          0         -1         -1         -1       0
13          0          0         -1         -1       0
14          0          0          0         -1       0
```

Comment: I took the liberty of boiling it down to this for the purposes of timing... brilliant answer btw!  `v = df.values; df.assign(Results=((v == v[:, [0]]) & v).cumprod(1).sum(1) * v[:, 0])`